# How to change the value of the "type" of an alias?

Tags: types, elasticsearch, alias

I am trying to change the name of the "type" of the alias that I am working on, do you know how I can do it ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by name of the type of the alias? Do you have a alias and want to change the index it points to?

Comment: I have an alias which is pointing to a type "_type: x_mobile". What I have done was I have generated a new type called: x_mobile_v2 as adding new properties inside, so now I want my alias point x_mobile_v2  instead of x_mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `add` and `remove` the alias in a single query like

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "remove" : { "index" : "x_mobile", "alias" : "alias_name" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "x_mobile_v2", "alias" : "alias_name" } }
    ]
}'
```

Also documentation says:

> This operation is atomic, no need to worry about a short period of
>   time where the alias does not point to an index:

More info:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

I just noticed that you asked about `type` alias, and not `index` alias. AFAIK there are no aliases for types so I assume you're looking for `index` alias.